# ASP.NET Grid View edit with variables

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, sql-server, gridview

When editing certain column values in my `gridview`, other values need to change depending on that value.

For example: https://i.stack.imgur.com/3hZL6.png

When editing the Truck Diesel column value, the KMPerLiter and RandsPerKM values must be changed according to that value and visa versa.  The formulas are as follows:

`KMPerLiter = TotaKM/TruckDiesel+TrailerDiesel and RandsPerKM = Amount/TotalKM.`

This must be done within the edit column of the `gridview`.

All these values are then stored in a table in a database.

Here is the ASP.Net html source code:

```
     UpdateCommand="UPDATE [Loads] SET [loadDate] = @loadDate, [loadDay] = @loadDay, [loadClient] = @loadClient, [loadDriver] = @loadDriver, [loadLoadingPoint1] = @loadLoadingPoint1, [loadLoadingPoint2] = @loadLoadingPoint2, [loadLoadingPoint3] = @loadLoadingPoint3, [loadOffloadingPoint1] = @loadOffloadingPoint1, [loadOffloadingPoint2] = @loadOffloadingPoint2, [loadOffloadingPoint3] = @loadOffloadingPoint3, [loadStops] = @loadStops, [loadNumber] = @loadNumber, [loadPodNumber] = @loadPodNumber, [loadAmount] = @loadAmount, [loadTruckReg] = @loadTruckReg, [loadTrailerReg] = @loadTrailerReg, [loadCategory] = @loadCategory, [loadDayOut] = @loadDayOut, [loadNightOut] = @loadNightOut, [loadOdoStart] = @loadOdoStart, [loadOdoEnd] = @loadOdoEnd, [loadTruckDiesel] = @loadTruckDiesel, [loadTrailerDiesel] = @loadTrailerDiesel, [loadInvoiceNumber] = @loadInvoiceNumber, [loadReceiptNumber] = @loadReceiptNumber, [loadKMperLiter] = @loadKMperLiter, [loadRandsPerKM] = @loadRandsPerKM, [loadDriverWage] = @loadDriverWage, [clientRecieved] = @clientRecieved, [loadTotalKM] = @loadTotalKM, [note] = @note WHERE [loadID] = @loadID">
    <UpdateParameters>
        <asp:Parameter DbType="Date" Name="loadDate" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="loadDay" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="loadClient" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="loadDriver" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="loadLoadingPoint1" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="loadLoadingPoint2" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="loadLoadingPoint3" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="loadOffloadingPoint1" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="loadOffloadingPoint2" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="loadOffloadingPoint3" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="loadStops" Type="Int32" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="loadNumber" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="loadPodNumber" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="loadAmount" Type="Decimal" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="loadTruckReg" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="loadTrailerReg" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="loadCategory" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="loadDayOut" Type="Int32" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="loadNightOut" Type="Int32" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="loadOdoStart" Type="Int32" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="loadOdoEnd" Type="Int32" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="loadTruckDiesel" Type="Decimal" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="loadTrailerDiesel" Type="Decimal" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="loadInvoiceNumber" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="loadReceiptNumber" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="loadKMperLiter" Type="Decimal" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="loadRandsPerKM" Type="Decimal" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="loadDriverWage" Type="Int32" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="clientRecieved" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="loadTotalKM" Type="Int32" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="note" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="loadID" Type="Int32" />
    </UpdateParameters>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I don't think you need the sql-server tag

Comment: Why not? It is all database related. The data in the grid view comes from a  connected sql database.

Comment: put some code. so that we can get a better idea

Comment: On Edit, column you can calculate the value you want to modify then call update statement for the  same table and bind the GridView again.

Comment: @Rojalin Sahoo is there anyway you could show me how that would be done?

Comment: @marnouxmanser upload your GridView coding I will share some coding on that.

Comment: @Rojalin Sahoo I uploaded the update statements for the grid view.  Am I supposed to use the <update parameters> to do the calculations?

Comment: @marnouxmanser then the best way is to create a stored procedure and  calculate your parameters on this and set update statement in that. After that call that procedure on UpdateCommand with Type as StoredProcedure.

Comment: @Rojalin Sahoo I am not experienced enough to cultivate such a solution as I am still a student. Is there anyway you can give me an example of your solution in the answer section?

Comment: @marnouxmanser given a rough idea about my suggestion please check it out if find any problem update me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Method 1:
Creating Stored Procedure

```
Create Proc _SPUpdateTableName
@id int,
@truckvalue numeric(18,0)
as 
 begin
   Update TableName set  KMPerLiter = TotaKM/(@truckvalue+TrailerDiesel) , TruckDiesel = @truckvalue  where ID =@id
end
```

On SqlDataSource code :

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="LocalServerDataSource" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:SiteSqlServer %>" UpdateCommand="_SPUpdateTableName" UpdateCommandType="StoredProcedure">
        <UpdateParameters>
            <asp:Parameter Name="id" Type="Int32" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="truckvalue " Type="Decimal" />
        </UpdateParameters>
    </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Or Else in RowUpdate Method you can calculate the parameters and assign them to your UpdateCommand statement Parameter :

Method 2:

```
  protected void grdvechile_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                decimal truckvalue= Convert.ToDecimal( grdvechile.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[1].Text);
               // fetch all value as needed and typecast
               decimal KMPerLiter = TotaKM/(truckvalue+TrailerDiesel);
               //Pass your required parameter
                LocalServerDataSource.UpdateParameters["truckvalue"].DefaultValue = truckvalue;
                LocalServerDataSource.UpdateParameters["KMPerLiter "].DefaultValue = KMPerLiter ;
                LocalServerDataSource.Update();
            }
            catch { }
        }
```

Note: These code is only on logic I thought will be appicable for your situation not tested.Change as per your Requirment.

Comment: Thank you very much Rojalin! Great answer.

Answer (score 0):

No need.. Only create a virtual table to pick up the Grid view value, Then change it according to your requirement, again reassign it to Grid view